# How the LZ77 compression algorithm handles the case when the entire look-ahead buffer is matched in the search buffer

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, coding-theory

The LZ77 compression algorithm uses a sliding window technique, where the window consists of a look-ahead puffer and a search-buffer. What I am wondering is how the algorithm handles the case if the match of the word in the search-buffer is the entire word in the look-ahead buffer? According to the desriptions I find, the algorithm matches as long as it can, and then outputs the offset, the length of the match and the next token after the matched portion in the look-ahead buffer, but in case the entire look-ahead buffer is matched we do not have a next token to output?

I nowhere find this case described, for example [the pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) just states "X first char after p in view", but I am asking about the case where we have no char after p in the view, as p is entire view?

For example, consider a search buffer of size 5 and a look-ahead buffer of size 4 and we read in

|abrar|rarr|ad

then we find a match at offset 3, and the match (which extends behind the boundary between both puffers, but this is no problem) goes up to all of rarr, even the next a could be matched, but what we should do now, should we output (3,4, C(a)) where C(a) denotes the code of a which is not in the look-ahead buffer, or should we just match the first 3 tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:  your look ahead buffer is no smaller than your longest match length. 
  As long as the start position is in the Search Buffer(a min of 1 byte), then the look-ahead buffer will have that one extra byte available to use as the follow byte

Comment: Yes, also thought to just reserve one more token in the look-a-head buffer, but this was nowhere mentioned so I asked here.